# Ajax reloading page

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am not too familiar with ajax, if you could help me that would be great.

The following script sends the data to my controller in Codeigniter and refreshes the page, however I was wondering if there was a way I could do this without the page totally reloading...hope that makes sense.

```
'onComplete' : function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
    $.post('<?=site_url('admin/news_manager/uploadify');?>',{filearray: response},function(info){
    location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omit the `location.reload();` from your script.

But if you want some part of the page to show data from the post, you need to insert that somewhere in the page.

In other words:

`$("#IdOfTheHtmlElement').html(info);` instead of  `location.reload();`

I hope this helps.